# Accessing req parameters for` Node.js` route before request is sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a Node.js server routes get request data as follows:

```
router.get("/dog", (req, res) => {
   // req.something...
});
```

For debugging purposes, I want to inspect what gets sent as the `req` object for a call like the following:

```
fetch("/app/dog").then(/*...*/)
```

Is there a way for me to access the **`req` parameters** before the request is sent? (Presumably I could do such debugging in my route, but I'm wanting to perform this inspection before making the fetch call). Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  What specific data are you looking to observe?  Is this `fetch` call being made from within a browser?  Do you need to access this data in code, or can you just observe the details of the request in your browser's debugging tools?  What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not sure to have understood on which level you want to check the request , but perhaps: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: @David Fetch call will be made from within a browser. I'm working with an existing `Node.js` component that uses a parameter `req.user` (the route blows up for the case of no user logged in, which is why I want to inspect if `req.user` is defined before making such a fetch)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this is exactly what I wanted to check - thanks. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: You said you wanted to check it before the request was sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use fetch, you might want to add functionality (methods) to the native `window.fetch` function which is not a good idea IMHO.
The simplest is to use (on the frontend) a library that already provides request [interceptors like **Axios**](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors).

Here's an example in which we send `name=doggo` as a request param,
we than modify the string to `"doggo intercepted"` still on the frontend,
we than modify that string on the backend using [Express Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to `"doggo intercepted and middlewared"` and finally log the final string in the designated route handler:

<sub>index.html</sub>

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Add a request interceptor
// https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  // Do something before request is sent:
  // Modify param name
  config.params.name += " intercepted"; // << modify the "doggo" string
  console.log(config);
  return config;
}, (err) => Promise.reject(err));


// Init GET request:
axios.get("/app/dog", {
  params: {
    name: "doggo"
  }
});
</script>
```

<sub>index.js (Node)</sub>

```js
import express from "express";
import path from "path"
import url from "url";
const __dirname = url.fileURLToPath(new URL(".", import.meta.url));

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Create a middleware:
// https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html
app.use('/app/:animal', (req, res, next) => {
  // If route "dog", do something
  if (req.params.animal === "dog") {
    req.query.name += " and middlewared"; // << modify the "doggo intercepted"
  }
  // Pass through
  next();
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/index.html"));
});

app.get("/app/dog", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query); // { name: 'doggo intercepted and middlewared' }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The short version is 'no'. The `req` parameter gets created *after* the request is sent by the client, and after it's headers are received by the server.